# Why doesn't sever send SYN/ACK after receive SYN from client?

Tags: tcp

I found the request from client timeout sometimes. And I use `tcpdump` to catch some special tcp package as follows. It seems no package was lost. Why the server doesn't reply to client after receiving the first SYN?

```
No.    Time     Src  Dst  Protocol Length   Info
 1   0.000000    C    S     TCP      66     46767→10660 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 2   0.996822    C    S     TCP      66     [TCP Retransmission] 46767→10660 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 3   0.996836    S    C     TCP      66     10660→46767 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 4   0.997117    C    S     TCP      54     46767→10660 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=0
 5   0.997127    C    S     TCP      500    46767→10660 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=446
 6   0.997130    S    C     TCP      54     10660→46767 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=447 Win=15744 Len=0
 7   1.017421    S    C     TCP      230    10660→46767 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=447 Win=15744 Len=176
 8   1.017681    C    S     TCP      54     46767→10660 [ACK] Seq=447 Ack=177 Win=15744 Len=0
 9   1.017686    C    S     TCP      54     46767→10660 [FIN, ACK] Seq=447 Ack=177 Win=15744 Len=0
10   1.020762    S    C     TCP      54     10660→46767 [FIN, ACK] Seq=177 Ack=448 Win=15744 Len=0
11   1.021486    C    S     TCP      54     46767→10660 [ACK] Seq=448 Ack=178 Win=15744 Len=0
```

---

Client package doesn't cary any tcp timestamp, so server needn't to set tcp_timestamp to 0.

---

This is captured on server.

Comment: Did you capture this traffic on the client or server machine? If you captured it on the client machine: why do you think that the server has received the packet?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hi, I captured this on server.

Comment: Maybe the backlog was full? What does the server set the listen backlog too?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. You are right. There are too many connection created at the same time and the backlog is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SYN will not get a SYN/ACK reply if the server's connection backlog is full.